# Make a ReportLab PDF interactive - Unable to reference widgets on PDF

Tags: python, user-interface, pdf, interactive, reportlab

I am currently building a ReportLab PDF Form which I want to make interactive. I want that the options shown on the second choice widget, depend on the selection of the first choice widget. (For example: if the selection of the first choice is 'Italy', show as food options on the second widget 'Pizza' and 'Spaghetti').

Currently I am trying to control such condition with an if, however I have been unable to reference the first widget correctly. (Since I called it name='choice1', I figured this would be the way of calling such widget). I get an error:

```
if choice1 == 'Italy':
NameError: name 'choice1' is not defined
```

Is there a correct way to do the desired action? I am looking at the [Reportlab documentation](https://www.reportlab.com/docs/reportlab-userguide.pdf), however I have not found an answer.

**My current Python code is the following:**

```
from reportlab.pdfgen.canvas import Canvas
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from reportlab.platypus import Table, TableStyle
from reportlab.lib import colors
from reportlab.pdfbase import pdfform
import win32com.client as win32
import pathlib

file_name = 'Example.pdf'
document_title = 'Example'
title = 'Example File'
instrucciones_1 = 'INSTRUCCIONES: Llenar toda la solicitud con la información que se pide.'
instrucciones_2 = 'Al finalizar, este PDF se enviará automáticamente al encargado de su área para aprobación.'
instrucciones_3 = 'La aprobación queda sujeta al criterio de dicho encargado. '

canvas = Canvas(file_name)
canvas.setTitle(document_title)

canvas.setFont("Helvetica-Bold", 24)
canvas.drawCentredString(385, 795, title)

now = datetime.now()
full_date = f'{now.day}/{now.month}/{now.year}'
canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 16)
canvas.drawCentredString(350, 790-20, 'Fecha solicitud: ')
canvas.setFont('Helvetica-Bold', 16)
canvas.drawCentredString(450, 790-20, full_date)

canvas.line(35, 755, 565, 755)
canvas.setFont("Helvetica", 12)
canvas.drawString(40, 740, instrucciones_1)
canvas.drawString(40, 740-15, instrucciones_2)
canvas.drawString(40, 740-30, instrucciones_3)
canvas.line(35, 740 - 35, 565, 740 - 35)


form = canvas.acroForm
canvas.setFont('Helvetica', 14)
canvas.drawString(70, 675, 'Origin of Food: ')
options = ['Select origin', 'Italy', 'Mexico', 'US']
form.choice(name='choice1', tooltip='Select origin of food',
            value='Select origin',
            x=165, y=670, width=200, height=25,
            borderColor=colors.blue, fillColor=colors.lightblue,
            textColor=colors.black, forceBorder=True, options=options)


origin = ''
food_italy = ['Select food', 'Spaghetti', 'Pizza']
food_mexico = ['Select food', 'Chiles en Nogada', 'Tacos]
food_us = ['Select food', 'Burgers', 'Buffalo Wings']


if choice1.value == 'Italy':
    sucursal = food_italy
elif choice1.value == 'Mexico':
    sucursal = food_mexico
elif choice1.value == 'US':
    sucursal = food_us

canvas.drawString(70, 645, 'Food: ')
form.choice(name='choice2', tooltip='Select food',
            value='Select food',
            x=165, y=670, width=200, height=25,
            borderColor=colors.blue, fillColor=colors.lightblue,
            textColor=colors.black, forceBorder=True, options=sucursal)

canvas.save()
```

Any suggestions?
Thanks a lot in advance!

**EDIT**

If PDF and Reportlab is not the way, is there some way I can do an executable file/form which can perform such tasks?  Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

This cannot be done in the way you approach this, i.e. in the Python code. The reason for this is that the selection of e.g. 'Italy' happens only when the user opens the PDF file and selects it. So you would need to create a (deprecated) XFA form for this.

Comment: Is there a way to do this? Maybe not in a PDF, but on an executable file of some sort in Python? I want to give it a try on Python before I do it in VBA and convert the file to a PDF which seems to me like a lot of unnecessary work.

Comment: As I said the only way this _could_ work is by using XFA forms. Standard PDF AcroForm doesn't support this. And it doesn't matter which programming language you use to create the PDF since you want that functionality in the PDF. And there this is not possible.